# Why isn't a const reference considered const using the is_const type trait?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I was rather surprised that the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << boolalpha << is_const<const float&>::value << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

Prints `false`. Removing the reference works correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << boolalpha << is_const<remove_reference<const float&>::type>::value << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

Printing out `true`.

Both were compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp`, using G++ version:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 5.3.0-1ubuntu1~14.04) 5.3.0 20151204
```

Thinking about it, I can understand that there are two types in play here: the reference type and the type that is referenced. The type that is referenced is `const`, so the second case makes sense. For the first case, I would expect it to either return if the referenced type is `const` or always `true` instead, because references AFAIK can't be "reassigned".

Why does it return `false` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outcome is correct.

References are never `const`, because they cannot be *cv-qualified*. You are correct in saying that they cannot be reassigned (and are, as such, immutable in a sense), but that is not the same as being `const`-qualified.

If you got `true` purely because the *referent* is `const`, then that would be completely inconsistent with the meaning of `is_const` in all other cases. Consider, for example, pointers. What should `is_const<int const*>::value` be?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The pointer example really made the case!